# Flink table join

Tags: apache-flink

When I try to join the data in the two message queues and save it to the database, but it fails. The code is as follows. When I added messages to the two message queues, no errors were reported, but there was no new data in the database. Could it be a problem with the way I join? Hope to get an answer! Thank you!

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
StreamTableEnvironment tableEnvironment = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

final RMQConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new RMQConnectionConfig.Builder()
                .setHost("localhost").setVirtualHost("goease-local")
                .setPort(5672).setUserName("guest").setPassword("guest")
                .build();
        
DataStream<DwdTrdOrderSubmitFactModel> orderSubmitDataStream = env.addSource(new RMQSource<>(
                connectionConfig,
                ORDER_SUBMIT_FACT_QUEUE,
                true,
                new OrderSchema()))
                .setParallelism(1).returns(DwdTrdOrderSubmitFactModel.class).process(new ProcessFunction<>() {
                    @Override
                    public void processElement(DwdTrdOrderSubmitFactModel value, Context ctx, Collector<DwdTrdOrderSubmitFactModel> out) {
                     
                    }
                });

        
DataStream<DimTrdMerchantModel> orderSubmitDimMerchantDataStream = env.addSource(new RMQSource<>(
                connectionConfig,
                ORDER_SUBMIT_DIM_MERCHANT_QUEUE,
                true,
                new OrderMerchantSchema()))
                .setParallelism(1).returns(DimTrdMerchantModel.class).process(new ProcessFunction<>() {
                    @Override
                    public void processElement(DimTrdMerchantModel value, Context ctx, Collector<DimTrdMerchantModel> out) {
                       
                    }
                });

Table orderSubmitTable = tableEnvironment.fromDataStream(orderSubmitDataStream, $("accountDimId"), $("disAccountDimId"), $("orderId"),
                $("orderNumber"), $("payFee"), $("taxFee"), $("logisticsFee"), $("createTime").rowtime());
Table orderSubmitMerchantTable = tableEnvironment.fromDataStream(orderSubmitDimMerchantDataStream, $("accountId"), $("nickname"), $("mobile"),
                $("email"), $("currency"), $("createTime2").rowtime());

tableEnvironment.createTemporaryView("orderSubmitTable", orderSubmitTable);
tableEnvironment.createTemporaryView("orderSubmitMerchantTable", orderSubmitMerchantTable);

Table order = tableEnvironment.sqlQuery("select * from orderSubmitTable");
tableEnvironment.toAppendStream(order, Row.class);

Table merchant = tableEnvironment.sqlQuery("select * from orderSubmitMerchantTable");
tableEnvironment.toAppendStream(merchant, Row.class);

Table result = order.leftOuterJoin(merchant).where($("accountDimId").isEqual($("accountId"))).select($("accountId"), $("payFee"));

        
//        Table result = tableEnvironment
//                .sqlQuery("select o.payFee, d.accountId from orderSubmitTable as o inner join orderSubmitMerchantTable d on o.accountDimId = d.accountId");

       
DataStream<OrderSubmitMerchantDTO> resultDs = tableEnvironment.toAppendStream(result, OrderSubmitMerchantDTO.class);
resultDs.addSink(new SinkToMySQL());
env.execute("joinDemo");
```